# Factory needs list of available objects. Should it be static or not?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, dependency-injection

I have a list of `IReader` that I read at the beginning of my program. Later on I need `ReaderFactory` to get appropriate `IReader` based on `Extensions` it can use. The problem is the factory needs to know about available readers. So I have two options:

1. Make static `ReaderFactory` with method `static Get(string
   extension)` and `static Init(IEnumerable<IReader> readers)` which
   would be called somewhere in my starting class.
2. Make `IReaderFactory` with constructor and `private
   IEnumerable<IReader> _readers` and make an instance of this and pass
   it via `Dependency Injection`.

My question is which one would you use in this particular situation? Also maybe there is a third option that I don't know about?

Comment: Since your factory needs configuration/inputs, the first one is never appropriate. That `Init` method is horrible.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a factory pattern, but more like a dictionary lookup.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Wouldn't your dictionary just be an implementation detail?  The same thing could be achieved with a `case` statement.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong, but should there be IEnumerable? or it should have been IEnumerator?

Comment: Have you looked at the managed extensibility framework (MEF) whilst you were researching this question?  It's probably what you need.  I'll post an answer with a sample later.

Comment: @JamesSnell Actually the project I was working on at that time used `MEF` extensively, and yes you are right. I could just export `ReaderFactory` and `ImportMany` readers. I think I have a couple of ways to solve this problem, and I think I'll post my own answer soon to close this question. I don't know why it was bumped to the homepage...

Answer (score 0):

It might be pedantic at this point, but I do not believe that the Factory Pattern is appropriate for this situation.

If I were asked to write the code with a gun to my head, I would likely make a Provider.

```
ReaderProvider {
    private IEnumerable<IReader> _readers;

    public ReaderProvider(IEnumerable<IReader> readers) {
        _readers = readers;
    }

    public IReader GetReaderForExtension(string extension) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could create this service when you read your list of readers, and inject the provider into the code that you require the reader.

If there is too much disconnect, you could use a singleton, but I generally tend to stay away from them when I can.

I hope that helps.

Comment: There is not really such a thing as "Factory Pattern". A factory is simply a class (or other unit) that returns instantiated objects. This is exactly what your example is doing. You are calling it a service, but it is a factory. In the original GoF book the "Factory Method" and "Abstract Factory" patterns are described, but neither is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Perhaps it is my opinion, but in my experience Factories tend to always be stateless. This is why I recommended creating a service, so  that there was no unintentional confusion over the state or lack there of.

Comment: Because you not creating new instances, the name ofthe class can be `ReaderProvider`

Answer (score 0):

I would use #2 since it would be easier to stub out during unit testing. The static factory would require some sort of mocking and interception in order to isolate away.

Answer (score 0):

Static anything are hard to unit test and also represent hidden dependencies, since they can be accessed from anywhere. Bad.

Instead, consider using your IoC container, but using ["singleton" scope](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance), e.g. with AutoFac you'd write this:

```
container.RegisterType<IReaderFactory, ReaderFactory>().SingleInstance();
```

The `ReaderFactory` can load the readers when it initializes itself. The initializer will be called only once and the same instance will be injected, with readers preloaded, into every class that depends on it.

If you do it this way you can still unit test, you haven't hidden any dependencies, and you maintain proper inversion of control with a single composition root.